# Are compound command's second and subsequent lines not effected by HISTCONTROL in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

When consulting bash's man page, it read this sentence about bash history:

> The second and subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command are
>   not tested, and are added to the history regardless of the value of
>   `HISTCONTROL`.

But I have tried this:

```
$ HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
$  if [ -f /var/log/messages ]
> then
> echo "/var/log/message exists."
> fi
$ history | tail -2
   18  HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
   19  history | tail -2
```

Note that the `if` is leaded by a space. Why the second line of this `if` compound command still not appear in the history?

Answer (score 2):

the multi line command will be one line for shell:

```
$  if [ -f /var/log/messages ]
> then
> echo "/var/log/message exists."
> fi
```

is the same like:

```
if [ -f /var/log/messages ]; then echo "/var/log/message exists."; fi
```

So if you put space on the one line command it will be ignored like history setting.

ADD: Effect of shell option cmdhist

```
shopt -s cmdhist # set cmdhist (is set by default)
if [ -d /tmp ]
> then
> echo Hello
> fi
Hello
history 2
43  if [ -d /tmp ]; then echo Hello; fi
44  history 2
```

In this case the multi-line command is concatenate to single line.

```
shopt -u cmdhist # unset cmdhist
if [ -d /tmp ]
> then
> echo Hello
> fi
Hello
history 5
   46  if [ -d /tmp ]
   47  then
   48  echo Hello
   49  fi
   50  history 5
```

In these case you see each line in the history separately.

If you now set the ignorespace option it should work on all the 4 line of if[].
So guess the disclaimer (in bash man) will say there not sure that it work all time with cmdhist=off. 
So ignoreoption will definitely not work on the second line "then". If you put a space  before "then" it will not be ignored. It works only at the first line but then for all next.

so the last example (not ignoring second line start with space)

```
if [ -d /tmp ]
>  then
> echo Hello
> fi
Hello
history 5
   66  if [ -d /tmp ]
   67   then
   68  echo Hello
   69  fi
   70  history 5
```

I hope this will answer you question.

Comment: Then, what does that sentence mean?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I guess there are sure if the ignore settings works 100% if the option cmdhist is off (shopts -u cmdhist). This shell option is on by default. See the effect in the ADD of answer. Just a guess !!!